# Best way to create students information site with django

Tags: django

I want to create a website for students with django.

I have **learning_plan** with n **subjects**

When I create a **student** I want to choose an existing learning_plan and have automatic all the subjects that the learning_plan has, also I want to have **exam_grades** different for each student.

What I've done so far:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class LearningPlan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, through='Exam')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    learning_plan = models.ForeignKey(LearningPlan)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Exam(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    learning_plan = models.ForeignKey(LearningPlan)
    exam_grade = models.IntegerField()
```

I know what I want I do not know how to do it. I want to have a plan with Subjects: Subject1, Subject2, Subject3 ... and when I add a new student I select a plan and see all the subjects from the grade associated to the student and to can add exam_grade to each of the Subjects (Subeject1, Subject2, Subject3 ...) and the grades for the same subject to be different for different students. I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: I would like to have at each student if I select a learning_plan all the subjects from the selected learning plan and the possibility to add exam_grades.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add some views, urls and templates. Or to use admin interface. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried the admin interface, but not as expected. I will try some more.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to help somebody if all that he says is "it does not work well" and "it does not work as expected".

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear speech. I know what I want I do not know how to do it. I want to have a plan with Subjects: Subject1, Subject2, Subject3 ... and when I add a new student I select a plan and see all the subjects from the grade associated to the student and to can add exam_grade to each of the Subjects (Subeject1, Subject2, Subject3 ...) and the grades for the same subject to be different for different students. Ido not know how to implement this.

Comment: Have you tried the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/)? It's a very good place to start.

Comment: I tried the tutorial and I understand the simple models, but when I get to more complex as descried in the comment above I do not understand yet how to implement it.

Comment: See my answer. Does it help, or problem is elsewhere?

Comment: DrTyrsa thank you for your answer. I have found a solution back than, your answer help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a student and what to get his (her) subjects, use this:

```
student.learning_plan.subjects.all()
```

Exam grades are simple too, but it's better to add `related_name` first:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    learning_plan = models.ForeignKey(LearningPlan, related_name='exams')
    exam_grade = models.IntegerField()
```

Now you can get student's exams:

```
student.learning_plan.exams.all()
```

And if you want to add an exam, it's still simple:

```
new_exam = Exam.objects.create(subject=some_subject, learning_plan=some_lp, exam_grade=98)
student.learning_plan.exams.add(new_exam)
```